# How to change appBar's back icon theme globally?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter automatically provides a back button for routes that can pop, but how can I change the back button Icon theme through the whole app?

Like how can I change the normal material back icon to **chevron**?

Answer (score 1):

Create pages without Scafold and use this method to navigate between routes.

```
navigateToRoute(BuildContext context, Widget page,String title) {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading:Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
      title: Text(title),
    ),
    body: page,
  )));
}
```

Comment: I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/get to navigate through many scaffolds

Comment: Replace the Navigator.push() method from my code ahe replace with Get.to() method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom `BackButton` in that case. I'll suggest that you can create a `customAppBar` method and use it everywhere.

Checkout the below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ScreenOne(),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenOneState createState() => _ScreenOneState();
}

class _ScreenOneState extends State<ScreenOne> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar(title: Text("Screen One")),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ScreenTwo()));
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenTwoState createState() => _ScreenTwoState();
}

class _ScreenTwoState extends State<ScreenTwo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar(
        customBackButton: true,
        title: Text("Screen Two"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

AppBar customAppBar({
  Widget title,
  bool customBackButton = false,
}) {
  return AppBar(
    leading: customBackButton ? CustomBackButton() : null,
    title: title,
  );
}

class CustomBackButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomBackButton({Key key, this.color, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;

  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
      color: color,
      tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).backButtonTooltip,
      onPressed: () {
        if (onPressed != null) {
          onPressed();
        } else {
          Navigator.maybePop(context);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think this is an acceptable solution, but is there another way to do it in `ThemeData()`?

Comment: @WailHayaly I don't think so there is any other way.

Answer (score -1):

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);[![Initially didn't put any color so it was white[![This is the image when I added appbartheme and changed color to black][1]][1]][1]
```

Comment: This `IconThemeData()` method only customize the **color**, **size** and **opacity** but I want to change the icon

Comment: For that, you will have to mention the Icon in the leading property of AppBar. You don't another option. You asked for iconThemeData which customize color, size, and opacity.

Comment: The question was specifically about setting the icon to a chevron.