# Change back icon for whole app at one not by doing manually on individual on each screens

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to change the back button icon for whole app not by changing it individually on screens i am unable to find out any placeholder to change the icon in app bar theme

there is no option for icon in appBarTheme

```
 appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              elevation: 0,
              systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light),
              titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: dark3)),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change appBar's back icon theme globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550126/how-to-change-appbars-back-icon-theme-globally)

Comment: this also does not has the answer!

Comment: Yes it doesn't because apparently there is no direct way to achieve it

The only way is to do the workaround shown the question

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.
If you are using Scaffold then under Scaffold in the appBar params there is one param called leading Icon. Change that and you'll get your desired icon as a Back Icon.

```
Scaffold(
 appbar:AppBar(
  leading:
    //<put that type of icons/widget you want to use >
  ),
 body: 
  //...
)
```

Comment: i want to change it al over the app not just in each screens

Comment: Check beloe answer

Answer (score -1):

make a custom appbar like this and use this wherever you need.

```
AppBar customAppBar()=>AppBar( 
 leading: //<put that type of icons/widget you want to use > 
//other params as per your requirement
);
```